# Azure Storage Account Geo Replication for File Shares?

Tags: azure, geo, azure-files, azure-storage-account

I have an Azure Storage Account and currently using File Shares with some folder structure, I need to enable Geo-Replication, It looks like Azure Storage Account does not support Geo-Replication for File Shares. Does it? If not, How do I handle the Geo-Replication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to enable the `Geo-Replication` of the storage account, which is also valid for `File Shares`.

Please refer to [Initiate a storage account failover](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-initiate-account-failover?tabs=azure-portal).

[image]

[image]

Please note:

[image]